# Работа с процентами

Tags: php

Написал функцию цель который предоставить информацию о пространстве в каталоге (Занятое пространство, свободное и сколько всего).

Используется так :

```
Wo_GetDisk("директория", "тип вывода (total, free, occupied)", "отображать ли данные в процентах (true / false)").
```

Если в последнем аргументе функции стоит false то данные выводятся в таком формате - *1024 MB/GB/KB* - (Всё как надо, с этим проблем нету).

Если true - в процентах.

Но проблема заключается в том, что я не знаю как предоставить эту же информацию, только в процентом виде - *25%* - Используется например, или свободно (Зависит от значения второго аргумента (total, free, occupied)).

(Я себе представляю абстрактно код который нужно написать чтобы всё работало, но на практике ничего не выходит. Если кто-то функцию посчитал полезной, то забирайте в своё пользование. Хотя мне кажется, я сделал очередной велосипед)

Сама чудо-функция :

```
function Wo_GetDisk($dir, $type, $percent)
{
   /*
    * Wo_SizeFormat - переводит байты в понятный нам формат (GB, 
      KB...) (Санитайзит вывод)
    * PATH - Константа абсолютного пути ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'])
    */
    if (isset($type) && isset($dir) && isset($percent)) {
        if (!empty($type) && !empty($dir) && !empty($percent)) {
            $free = disk_free_space(PATH . $dir);
            $total = disk_total_space(PATH . $dir);
            $occupied = $total - $free;

            switch ($type) {
                case "total":
                {
                    if ($percent === true) {
                        return "Total в процетах...";
                    }
                    else {
                        return Wo_SizeFormat($total);
                    }
                }
                case "free":
                {
                    if ($percent === true) {
                        return "Free в процетах...";
                    }
                    else {
                        return Wo_SizeFormat($free);
                    }
                }
                case "occupied":
                {
                    if ($percent === true) {
                        return "Occupied в процетах...";
                    }
                    else {
                        return Wo_SizeFormat($occupied);
                    }
                }
                default:
                {
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Покажет свободное пространство: $percent = $free * 100 / $total;

Покажет занятое пространство: $percent = 100 - $free * 100 / $total ;

Comment: Спасибо, всё работает!